# Access Geometry Child Node Scenekit

Tags: swift, scenekit, scene, child-nodes

I am trying to access the childnode: boxNode, and then rotate the node using the input from a pan gesture recognizer. How should I access this node so I can manipulate it? Should I declare the cube node in a global scope and modify that way? I am new to Swift so I apologize if this code looks sloppy. I would like to add rotation actions inside of my panGesture() function. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scnView: SCNView!
var scnScene: SCNScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
    setupScene()
}

//  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
//    return true
//  }
//
//  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
//    return true
//  }

func setupView() {
    scnView = self.view as! SCNView
}

func setupScene() {
    scnScene = SCNScene()
    scnView.scene = scnScene
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    initCube()
    initLight()
    initCamera()
}

func initCube () {
    var cubeGeometry:SCNGeometry
    cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
}

func initLight () {
    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light
    light.castsShadow = false
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, z: 1.5)
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
}

func initCamera () {
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 5.0)
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
}

func initRecognizer () {
    let panTestRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.panGesture(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panTestRecognizer)
}

//TAKE GESTURE INPUT AND ROTATE CUBE ACCORDINGLY
func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update your Xcode. It looks like this is an older Swift version you are using. `SCNLightTypeAmbient` is `.ambient` in Swift 3.

So the way you should go is by giving your nodes names to identify them:

`myChildNode.name = "FooChildBar"`

and then you can call on your parent node

`let theNodeYouAreLookingFor = parentNode.childNode(withName: "FooChildBar", recursively: true)`

You can also use this on your scene's root node

`let theNodeYouAreLookingFor = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "FooChildBar", recursively: true)`

which will look at all nodes in your scene and return the one that you gave the name.